# Как заставить бота оставлять реакцию под каждым сообщением в выбранном канале?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Помогите, пожалуйста, с функцией на discord.py: бот должен ставить определенный смайлик в реакцию под каждое сообщение в выбранном мной канале.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    if msg.channel.id == channel.id:
        msg.add_reaction('✋') # источник https://getemoji.com/ подобного вида эмодзи
```

вместо channel_id вставишь id нужного канала